# Nvidia nvprof: Observe PyTorch CUDA calls

Tags: python, cuda, profiling

I've written a small PyTorch program which just does one 2D convolution on the GPU.

Now I would like to observe the kernel calls / runtimes with nvprof - is this possible and if so - how?

I am used to calling nvprof with my combined C++ CUDA program but not with a python script.

Can this be done?

Comment: `nvprof python my_script.py`

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you, I wasn't aware that this is possible